# Getting a js filter to work to show menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys so i am building a simple filter for restaurant menus right now. 
I have three menus `"menu1" "menu2" "menu3"` And i want the customer to be able to click a button and that will show the correct menu. However for some reason i cant seem to get it to work at all.

So i want it to just show `"menu1"` at the start so i gave `"menu2 & 3"` a `display: none;` and when the user clicks on the button to show `menu2 or 3` it will show the correct menu , However i cant get this to work:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="categories">
        <ul class="cat">
          <li>
            <ol class="type">
              <li><a href="#" class="active" id="menu1">Menu1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"  id="menu2">Menu2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"  id="menu3">Menu3</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">FirstMenu</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> $35 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu2">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">SecondMenu</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> $45 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu3">
          <h2 class="menu-section-title">ThridMenu</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
            <div class="menu-item-price"> $45 </div>
            <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu2 {
    display: none;
}

.menu3 {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#showall').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
  });
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('.div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
  });
});
```

I tried to use an example to make it work but i have no idea what i am doing and how i can get this to work, any help on this matter would be great

Thanks

Comment: Where should the user click to make other menu's visible?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/39755/

Comment: @gurvinder372 the buttons are there

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thats not what i was trying to acheive, i just want the user to be able to click on a button and that button will show menu 1 or menu2 or menu3

Comment: Sorry my English is not the best so i might have not explained it well at all

Comment: @RonTheOld Sorry, I don't see a button in your markup.

Comment: @gurvinder372 no problem , again its my fault,  my explanation was bad  , i have 3 buttons and whatever button they click i want that to show the right menu if that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the event handler on `"li a"` and toggle the visibility of `targetDiv`s.

```
$( "li a[id]" ).click( function(){
  $( ".targetDiv" ).hide().filter( "." + this.id ).show();
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("li a[id]").click(function() {
  $(".targetDiv").hide().filter("." + this.id ).show();
})
```

```css
.menu2 {
  display: none;
}

.menu3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="categories">
      <ul class="cat">
        <li>
          <ol class="type">
            <li><a href="#" class="active" id="menu1">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menu2">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="menu3">Menu3</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu1">
        <h2 class="menu-section-title">FirstMenu</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="menu-item">
          <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
          <div class="menu-item-price"> $35 </div>
          <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu2">
        <h2 class="menu-section-title">SecondMenu</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="menu-item">
          <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
          <div class="menu-item-price"> $45 </div>
          <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="menu-section targetDiv menu3">
        <h2 class="menu-section-title">ThridMenu</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="menu-item">
          <div class="menu-item-name"> Delicious Dish </div>
          <div class="menu-item-price"> $45 </div>
          <div class="menu-item-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, duis sed dapibus leo nec ornare diam. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RonTheOld Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easier, just use a global class for your `menu`/`buttons` hide all menu by default.
when you `click` on your button `hide` all menu and show only the right menu.

```js
$(".btn-menu").click(function(){
  var menuid = $(this).data("menuid");
  $(".menu").hide();
  $(".menu"+menuid).show();
})
```

```css
.menu{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-menu" data-menuid="1">Show menu 1</button>
<button class="btn-menu" data-menuid="2">Show menu 2</button>
<button class="btn-menu" data-menuid="3">Show menu 3</button>
<div class="menu menu1">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menu menu2">Menu 2</div>
<div class="menu menu3">Menu 3</div>
```

Comment: Ah this also works great, however i did want to show the menu 1 by default and then they can click on menu 2 and 3

Comment: Just update the css, instead of .menu => .menu2,.menu3